# Formatting DDL values populated from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

noob question: my basic Rails app has a DB with Categories and Soups (yup, from Code School), with the class Category containing many Soups.  I'm adding the ability for the user to add Categories and Soups with a form.  For adding new Soups, I want the user to be able to assign a Category from the available DB list.

Instead of 1 dropdown list showing 3 categories, I get 3 DDLs, each showing 3 values like `#<Category:0x007fbbdceb50db>`.  How can I have the correct values appear in a single DDL?  Categories have "id" and "name" values while Soups have "id", "name", and "category_id" values.

Thanks for any and all help.

categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @categories = Category.all
    end

  def show
    @categories = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new

  end

  def create
    @categories = Category.new(params.require(:categories).permit(:name))

    @categories.save
    redirect_to @categories
  end
end
```

soups_controller.rb

```
class SoupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :fetch_soup, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :toggle_feature]

  def index
    @soups = Soup.all
  end

  def show
    @soups = Soup.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new

  end

  def create
    @soups = Soup.new(params.require(:soups).permit(:name, :category_id))

    @soups.save
    redirect_to @soups
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<p>Add new soup</p>
<%= form_for :soups, url: soups_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :CategoryID %>

    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(@categories, 'name') %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `options_from_collection_for_select` helper which knows how to take a collection of ActiveRecord models and turn them into DDL options.

You need to pass (1) the collection (2) the method to use for the value of the option and (3) the method to use for the ID of the option.

In your case,

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :name, :id)
```

[See the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! You should mark one of these answers as the accepted solution so that others can see what solved your problem and benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `collection_select` instead.  It would look something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:soup, :category_id, Categories.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Select the category") %>
```

More info: [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select)